# ArrayList retornando valores nulos

Tags: java, array

Bom, tenho uma matriz, adiciono valores nessa matriz, envio para um método em outra classe que  coloca os valores dessa matriz em uma string apenas e adiciono essa única string em uma ArrayList, porém quando vou exibir, mostra apenas vários "null".

classe principal:

```
class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Logica chamar = new Logica(valores);
        String[][] valores = new String[3][2];
        ArrayList colecao = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Insira um nome.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Insira um número.");
                } valores[i][j] = entrada.next();
            }
        } colecao.add(chamar);
        for (Object resolucao:colecao) {
            System.out.println(resolucao.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

classe lógica:

```
class Logica {
    String valores;
    public Logica(String[][] valores) {
        valores = new String[3][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                this.valores = valores[i][j] + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
        return valores;
    }
}
```

O que está errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu código possui alguns erros, vou explicar as modificações que precisariam ser realizadas:

### Classe principal:

Seu código demonstra um costume, possivelmente herdado de programação em C, que é declarar todas as variáveis no começo do método antes de utilizá-las. No Java você não é obrigado a fazer isso, inclusive pode até causar problemas na sua lógica, por exemplo nesse trecho:

```
Logica chamar = new Logica(valores);
String[][] valores = new String[3][2];
```

Isso nem sequer compila. Você está passando a variável `valores` para o construtor da classe `Logica` antes mesmo de `valores` ser declarada. Acredito que o que você quer é chamar essa linha:

```
Logica chamar = new Logica(valores);
```

logo abaixo dos `for` encadeados, isto é, logo acima dessa outra linha:

```
colecao.add(chamar);
```

Com isso o seu objeto `chamar` vai receber os `valores` já preenchidos pelo usuário, o que não acontece quando `new Logica(valores)` é executado antes do `for`.

### Classe lógica:

Essa classe tem uma linha que não deveria existir...

```
valores = new String[3][2];
```

...pois nessa linha você perde os valores passados à classe `Logica` por meio do seu construtor. Já existe uma linha inicializando a variável `valores` com os tamanhos `[3][2]` na classe principal, não é preciso fazer isso aqui de novo. Reinicializando a variável dessa forma você faz `valores` referenciar um novo objeto `array` que não irá conter os valores preenchidos pelo usuário; portanto, essa linha deve ser removida.

Por último, se o que você deseja fazer é concatenar cada valor e formar uma única grande string com os valores concatenados, deve trocar essa linha:

```
this.valores = valores[i][j] + "\n";
```

por essa:

```
this.valores = this.valores + valores[i][j] + "\n";
```

ou então por uma versão que utiliza o operador `+=`:

```
this.valores += valores[i][j] + "\n";
```

Uma última recomendação: você está usando o mesmo nome (`valores`) para uma variável que é campo de sua classe `Logica` e para outra que é parâmetro do construtor dessa classe. Evite usar o mesmo nome nas duas, pois isso torna o código menos legível e pode inclusive causar confusão e erros lógicos quando o código precisa ser modificado. Usando nomes diferentes para cada uma das variáveis você inclusive está livre de usar o `this` para especificar que está se referindo a uma e não à outra no seu código.

Comment: Fiz as alterações, funcionou como o esperado, porém, na hora de exibir, aparece um "null" na primeira linha antes dos dados inseridos. Ficou "nullvalor", o restante está normal. De onde poderia estar surgindo esse null?

Comment: Ah, acho que é por que a variável global `valores` começa como nula.

Comment: @Patrick Creio que é porque na classe `Logica` faltou declarar o valor do atributo `valores` assim: `String valores = "";`