# Como exibir os valores de um ArrayList separadamente?

Tags: java, foreach

```
class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList colecao = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.println("Insira um nome.");
                colecao.add(entrada.next());
            }
        } for (Object resolucao:colecao) {
            String formato = "| %-15s | %-10s |%n";
            System.out.format("+---------------+----------+%n");
            System.out.printf("| Nome          | Nome 2   |%n");
            System.out.format("+---------------+----------+%n");
            System.out.format(formato, resolucao, resolucao + "%n");
            System.out.format("+---------------+----------+%n");
        }
    }
}
```

Preciso exibir separadamente usando um for-each e aí é que está o problema, como exibir o item certo na coluna certa?

Comment: Defina "tudo junto". `resolucao` será sempre um objeto, você quer imprimir uma propriedade dele?

Comment: Quero imprimir os valores do ArrayList `exemplo` usando um for-each, ex.: no índice 0 do exemplo tem a string `"lápis"`, no índice 1 a string `"caneta"`, quando imprime, fica `"lápiscaneta"`, mas quero imprimir de forma separada, `"lápis"` e `"caneta"`.

Comment: Saída no console.

Comment: Acho que fui falho em explicar, na realidade, preciso separar uma string em duas, ex.: `"lápiscaneta"` que está no índice 0 em `"lápis"`, no índice 0 e `"caneta"`, no índice 1.
É isso ou fazer o método que recolhe os dados retornar uma matriz para popular o ArrayList.

Comment: Esse código é exatamente o que estou a fazer, a única diferença é que no for está `this.valores += valores[i][j]`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13488/arraylist-retornando-valores-nulos

Comment: Arrume o this.valores += valores[i][j] para this.valores += valores[i][j] + '\n' Ou então crie uma array separada e use arrayseparada.add( valores[i][j] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Esta resposta era para uma versão anterior que a pergunta já teve.

O `println` já deveria quebrar as linhas, tente a variante abaixo, caso seja um problema de diferença de plataforma:

```
ArrayList exemplo = new Arraylist();
for (Object resolucao: exemplo) {
   System.out.println(resolucao);
}
```

**Baseado num comment seu**, você pode dividir uma string desta forma, caso sua origem não seja um array:

```
Exemplo = original.split("\\n");

for (Object resolucao: exemplo) {
   System.out.println(resolucao + "\r\n");
}
```

Quanto à quebras de linha:

Para saber a quebra de linha da plataforma em uso, o Java possui o

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Ou a partir do Java 7,

```
String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
```

Comment: Já tentei fazê-lo, porém ele imprime todos os índices e só depois pula a linha.

Comment: Ele vai quebrar a linha onde tiver um `"\n"`?

Comment: @Patrick De qualquer forma, acho que é o caso de você editar e consertar a pergunta pondo o código exato que está usando, senão fica um monte de consa bagunçada aqui no site, e respostas que não ajudam ninguem.

Comment: Quis dizer, ele vai dividir a string onde tiver um `"\n"`?

Comment: @Patrick sim, mas se sua string for "banana|macaco", basta trocar o "\\n" por "|", por exemplo. Ali vai um parâmetro Regex.